# How to pack +-1 signs of 8 packed 32-bit integers (in an __m256i) into bytes of a 64-bit integer?

Tags: c++, performance, simd, intrinsics, avx2

Given an `__m256i` worth of packed 32-bit signed integers, how to get a single 64-bit number where each byte is `1` if the corresponding 32-bit signed integer from the original `__m256i` is greater than or equal to 0, and get `-1` if that 32-bit integer is negative?

AVX2 (and probably AVX512) are of interest.

Comment: What are you going to do with the +1 / -1 bytes?  Do you want them in a SIMD vector, an array in memory, an `int64_t` in an integer register, or what?  Do you have multiple vectors of input to turn into a larger array of sign bytes, so a 4-input function producing a `__m256i` of 32 bytes would be useful, using 2-input packs?  Are they going to be a mask for something else?  Why not 0 / -1 which is cheaper to generate (e.g. `_mm256_srai_epi32(v, 31)` or a compare)?  If AVX-512, can you just extract the sign bits to a mask register and use a merge-masked operation in whatever you're doing next?

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm then going to multiply them by `(-1, 0, 1)` numbers, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76947456/how-to-decompress-bit-pairs-from-uint64-t-to-m256i . There is tricky packing going on to save the CPU cache. I have multiple vectors - about 4K total scalar values. Yes, I want 4 such 64-bit integers into a `__m256i` register.

Comment: Multiply by (-1, 0, 1) would be very easy to do on bytes (psignb)

Comment: x86 doesn't have SIMD 8-bit multiply, except for `pmaddubsw` which accumulates pairs horizontally into 16-bit sums of products.  So you actually want to conditionally negate something else according to the sign bits of your 32-bit elements.  The most efficient way to do that won't involve creating vectors of +1 / -1 `int8_t`.  One better way would be to pack down to `0` or `-1` byte elements which you can use with XOR and ADD to negate or not.  (`-x = ~x + 1`, so `(x ^ signs) - signs` is a no-op for 0 and `-x` for signs=-1, the same trick as the usual bithack abs() but not applied to itself)

Comment: So you just want `_mm256_packs_epi32(v0,v1)` to get 16-bit elements with the same sign bit, then `_mm256_srai_epi16(tmp, 15)` to broadcast the sign bit.  Or actually pack all the way to 8-bit with signed pack, then `_mm256_cmpgt_epi8( _mm256_setzero_si256(), tmp)` to do `0 > v`, i.e. set the byte according to its sign bit.  Or instead of that + bithack, use `vpblendvb` to select between original and `0 - x` results.  But maybe you can use that 0 / -1 during decoding of your 2-bit packed fields more efficiently, like perhaps one XOR or SUB before `vpshufb` lookups?

Comment: Anyway, if you want the result in a SIMD vector for use with another vector, it's super weird that you accepted the `pdep` answer.  Your [How to decompress bit pairs from uint64\_t to \_\_m256i?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76947456) question should describe the full problem, including the conditional negation according to the signs of 32-bit elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s another approach.

It requires BMI2 support for PDEP instruction, only fast on Intel, and AMD starting with Zen 3 microarchitecture.

```
// Convert sign bits of 8 int32 lanes into -1 / +1 bytes
uint64_t packSigns( __m256i vec )
{
    // Bitcast to FP32 vector, compiles into no instructions
    __m256 fv = _mm256_castsi256_ps( vec );
    // Move sign bits to general-purpose register
    uint64_t bits = (uint32_t)_mm256_movemask_ps( fv );
    // Expand bits into bytes
    constexpr uint64_t lowBits = 0x0101010101010101ull;
    bits = _pdep_u64( bits, lowBits );
    // Convert 0 / +1 bytes into +1 / -1 bytes
    return ( bits * 0xFF ) | lowBits;
}
```

Comment: @harold Good question. See the edit, saved one instruction.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your result to +1 / -1 as `__m256i` vector, then compress it with series of packs.

The first step can be done:

- Using `_mm256_srai_epi32(val, 31)` followed by `or` with `_mm256_set1_epi32(1)`, as Peter Cordes suggested
- Using `_mm256_sign_epi32(_mm256_set1_epi32(1), values)`, as Harold suggested, followed by `or` with `_mm256_set1_epi32(1)` as Peter Cordes observed
- like this, knowing that the sign as well as the mask bit of `float` and `int32_t` is at the same position:

```c
__m256i plus_or_minus_pi32 =  _mm256_castps_si256(_mm256_blendv_ps(
  _mm256_castsi256_ps(_mm256_set1_epi32(+1)),
  _mm256_castsi256_ps(_mm256_set1_epi32(-1))
  _mm256_castsi256_ps(val)));
```

Then `_mm256_packs_epi32` followed by a shuffle and then another `_mm256_packs_epi16` can compress it to the `int8_t` vector.

Finally, convert to GRP if you need, by `_mm256_extract_epi64` with zero parameter.

Comment: Another strategy would start with an arithmetic right shift by 31 (`_mm256_srai_epi32(v, 1)`) to get 0 / -1 values, then OR with `set1_epi8(1)` after packing.  Since `blendv` costs 2 uops on Intel CPUs, this comes out ahead (esp. if packing multiple vectors down to one, or you can do the OR in scalar).  It also avoids the vector constants.  Note that AVX2 pack instructions are *not* lane-crossing, so you'll need a shuffle after your two rounds of in-lane packing.

Comment: @harold: [`vpsignd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/psignb:psignw:psignd) zeros the value on input = 0.  The OP wants `1` in that case, so we'd still have to scalar OR with `0x0101010101010101` at the end to turn any zeros into 1s, and leave any -1s unchanged.  A shift produces 0 / -1 without needing a vector constant.

Comment: @harold: your scalar strategy using `pdep` could be fixed with an OR with `0x01...`, the same constant the compiler already needs in a register for `pdep` so it's efficient (except on Zen 2 and earlier).  That's actually quite good in total uop count, I think, if you only have one vector.