# How to decompress bit pairs from uint64_t to __m256i?

Tags: c++, performance, vectorization, simd, avx

Consider `uint64_t` where each consecutive 2 bits is a number: `b00` for `0`, `b01` for `1`, `b11` for `-1` and `b10` is unused (never happens, assume no handling for it).
How to decompress such an `uint64_t` into `__m256i` so that bit pairs from the original number become signed bytes in the vector variable? I need to unpack `b00` into `b00000000`, `b01` into `b00000001` and `b11` into `b11111111`, while preserving the order.

What I have tried so far:
Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76946161/1915854), I only have come up with the inverse procedure, where bytes of `__m256i` are packed into bit pairs of an `uint64_t`:

```
const __m256i vBits0 = _mm256_slli_epi16(target, 7);
const int bits1 = _mm256_movemask_epi8(target);
const int bits0 = _mm256_movemask_epi8(vBits0);
const uint64_t withHigher = _pdep_u64(bits1, 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA);
const uint64_t withLower =  _pdep_u64(bits0, 0x5555555555555555);
return withHigher | withLower;
```

I have access to AVX2, but AVX512 would be also of interest.

Comment: Unpacking bytes to 4-bit halves is fairly well known for using `vpshufb` as a LUT; another modified round of that should be possible to get 2-bit quarters of bytes.  Like shift (and maybe mask) and `_mm256_unpacklo_epi8` / `_mm256_unpackhi_epi8` to interleave.  (In-lane shuffle; would need a `vpermd` or something to fix that up.  If you start with one `__m256i` input, you should get four `__m256i` outputs.  The actual translation from 2-bit values to bytes might be done with `vpshufb`, except shuffle throughput could be a limiting factor since you also need shuffles to unpack.)

Comment: Consider changing your storage format. The quickest round-trip compress/decompress would probably use `pavgb`, with interleaved bit ordering.

Comment: Also note, the OP wants to conditionally negate these based on the sign bits of arrays of 32-bit integers (per comments on [How to pack +-1 signs of 8 packed 32-bit integers (in an \_\_m256i) into bytes of a 64-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/135648043)), for arrays of 4K elements, not a single `uint64_t`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you wanted an AVX512 solution (requires the VBMI extension):

```c
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>

__m256i bits_to_bytes(uint64_t a) {
    const __m256i shuffle_bits = _mm256_set_epi8(
            62, 60, 58, 56, 54, 52, 50, 48, 46, 44, 42, 40, 38, 36, 34, 32, 30,
            28, 26, 24, 22, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0);
    const __m256i new_bytes = _mm256_set1_epi32(0xfffe0100);

    __m256i same = _mm256_set1_epi64x(a);
    __m256i extracted_bits = _mm256_multishift_epi64_epi8(shuffle_bits, same);

    // vpermb ignores high bits ...
    return _mm256_permutexvar_epi8(extracted_bits, new_bytes);

    // ... or mask off the upper bits and use vpshufb
    // const __m256i low_bits = _mm256_set1_epi8(3);
    // return _mm256_shuffle_epi8(new_bytes, _mm256_and_si256(low_bits, extracted_bits));
}
```

If your data is in memory, that can end up being two instructions, something like:

```
vpmultshiftqb ymm0, ymm1, [rax]{1to4}
vpermb ymm0, ymm0, ymm2
```

But GCC seems reluctant to fold in the memory operand as a broadcast.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s one naïve method when you have fast BMI2.

```
// Expand signed 2-bit fields into signed bytes in the AVX2 vector, with BMI2
__m256i expand2_bmi( uint64_t bitmap )
{
    // Use BMI to extend 2 bit fields into bytes,
    // each instruction transforms 16 bits into 8 bytes
    constexpr uint64_t dep2 = 0x0303030303030303ull;
    uint64_t i0 = _pdep_u64( bitmap, dep2 );
    uint64_t i1 = _pdep_u64( bitmap >> 16, dep2 );
    uint64_t i2 = _pdep_u64( bitmap >> 32, dep2 );
    uint64_t i3 = _pdep_u64( bitmap >> 48, dep2 );

    // Assemble AVX2 vector with these numbers, probably 5 instructions
    __m256i v = _mm256_setr_epi64x( i0, i1, i2, i3 );

    // Lookup table to sign extend
    const __m256i perm = _mm256_set1_epi32( 0xFFFE0100 );
    v = _mm256_shuffle_epi8( perm, v );
    return v;
}
```

Here’s another idea which doesn’t require BMI2.

```
// Expand signed 2-bit fields into signed bytes in the AVX2 vector
__m256i expand2_vec( uint64_t bitmap )
{
    // Move to SSE vector
    __m128i v16 = _mm_cvtsi64_si128( (int64_t)bitmap );
    // Zero-extend bytes into uint32_t lanes
    __m256i v = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi32( v16 );

    // Split pairs of 4-bit fields into uint16_t lanes
    __m256i tmp = _mm256_slli_epi32( v, 12 );
    v = _mm256_or_si256( v, tmp );

    // Split pairs of 2-bit fields into uint8_t lanes
    tmp = _mm256_slli_epi16( v, 6 );
    v = _mm256_or_si256( v, tmp );

    // The above 4 instructions left garbage in bits 2-7 of most bytes
    // Sadly, the pollution affects bits 7, 15 and 23 which cause vpshufb to output zeros
    // That's why need yet another constant vector
    v = _mm256_and_si256( v, _mm256_set1_epi8( 0b11 ) );

    // Lookup table to sign extend
    const __m256i perm = _mm256_set1_epi32( 0xFFFE0100 );
    v = _mm256_shuffle_epi8( perm, v );
    return v;
}
```

Tested very little.

I have no idea which one of them is faster. I would expect it to depend on use case, surrounding code, and maybe even compiler switches.

BMI2 version has more instructions, however many pieces will run in parallel. AVX2-only version has fewer instructions, but there’s a single chain of data dependencies across the complete function, also two vector constants to load from memory instead of a single one.

Comment: If doing this over multiple uint64_t inputs, you have parallelism between chunks.  According to [late comments](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/135648043) on the OP's other question, they have about 4K scalar values they want to use with their unpacked 2-bit values, multiplying by `-1` or `+1` (which is a really bad approach, you don't want to actually multiply and there's no instruction for it).  If they also have 4K 2-bit elements, that's 1024 bytes = 128 `__m256i` vectors; plenty of data parallelism for out-of-order exec.  A better question would have mentioned this.

Answer (score 1):

The tested solution below is probably not going to win a prize for best performance but it uses a very simple approach that may make it easier to port it to non-x86 platforms later. I build this with Intel compilers `icl` (classic) and `icx` (clang-based) as ISO-C99 code, for an AVX2 platform.

Basically, I spread out each bit pair to a separate byte and isolate it. I then compute the mapping from the bit pair (which in general is *not* right-aligned inside the byte) to the desired result. With some more thought this mapping process could probably be accelerated but given limited time I solved it by expanding each bit of the bit pair into a byte mask *separately*, then combined the masks to compute the final result.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "immintrin.h"

#define TEST_CASES (100000000)

__m256i decompress (uint64_t a)
{
    const __m256i ones = _mm256_set1_epi8 (1);
    const __m256i byte_mask = _mm256_set_epi32 (0x07070707, 0x06060606, 
                                                0x05050505, 0x04040404,
                                                0x03030303, 0x02020202, 
                                                0x01010101, 0x00000000);
    const __m256i bit_mask_l = _mm256_set1_epi32 (0x40100401);
    const __m256i bit_mask_h = _mm256_set1_epi32 (0x80200802);
    /* spread the bits: bits<1:0> to byte 0, bits>3:2> to byte 1, etc. */
    __m256i aa = _mm256_set1_epi64x (a);
    __m256i ma = _mm256_shuffle_epi8 (aa, byte_mask);
    __m256i lo = _mm256_and_si256 (ma, bit_mask_l);
    __m256i hi = _mm256_and_si256 (ma, bit_mask_h);
    /* convert bits to byte mask, separately for high/low bit of a bit pair */
    __m256i hi_cmp = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8 (hi, bit_mask_h);
    __m256i lo_cmp = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8 (lo, bit_mask_l);
    /* create result from masks for low and high bits */
    __m256i temp = _mm256_and_si256 (lo_cmp, ones);
    __m256i res = _mm256_or_si256 (temp, hi_cmp);

    return res;
}

__m256i decompress_ref (uint64_t a)
{
    __m256i res;
    uint8_t t [32];
    for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
        int bit_pair = a >> (2 * i) & 0x3;
        switch (bit_pair) {
        case 2: 
            /* don't care; fall through */
        case 3:
            t[i] = (uint8_t)(-1);
            break;
        case 1:
            t[i] = (uint8_t)(1);
            break;
        case 0:
        default :
            t[i] = (uint8_t)0;
            break;
        }
    }
    memcpy (&res, t, sizeof res);
    return res;
}

/*
  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.lang.c/qFv18ql_WlU/IK8KGZZFJx4J
  From: geo <gmars...@gmail.com>
  Newsgroups: sci.math,comp.lang.c,comp.lang.fortran
  Subject: 64-bit KISS RNGs
  Date: Sat, 28 Feb 2009 04:30:48 -0800 (PST)

  This 64-bit KISS RNG has three components, each nearly
  good enough to serve alone.    The components are:
  Multiply-With-Carry (MWC), period (2^121+2^63-1)
  Xorshift (XSH), period 2^64-1
  Congruential (CNG), period 2^64
*/
static uint64_t kiss64_x = 1234567890987654321ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_c = 123456123456123456ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_y = 362436362436362436ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_z = 1066149217761810ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_t;
#define MWC64  (kiss64_t = (kiss64_x << 58) + kiss64_c, \
                kiss64_c = (kiss64_x >> 6), kiss64_x += kiss64_t, \
                kiss64_c += (kiss64_x < kiss64_t), kiss64_x)
#define XSH64  (kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y << 13), kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y >> 17), \
                kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y << 43))
#define CNG64  (kiss64_z = 6906969069ULL * kiss64_z + 1234567ULL)
#define KISS64 (MWC64 + XSH64 + CNG64)

void print_256i (const char *s, __m256i a)
{
    uint8_t t [32];
    memcpy (t, &a, sizeof t);
    printf ("%s: ", s);
    for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf ("%02x", (unsigned int)t[i]);
        if (i) printf (",");
    }
    printf ("\n");
}

int main (void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < TEST_CASES; i++) {
        uint64_t a = KISS64;
        __m256i res = decompress (a);
        __m256i ref = decompress_ref (a);
        if (memcmp (&res, &ref, sizeof res)) {
            printf ("arg: %016" PRIx64 "\n", a);
            print_256i ("res", res);
            print_256i ("ref", ref);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```